# I can't call a method in the onPressed property (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

i tried to access a method from my global variables file, but i dont know how. This is the main code that i'm trying to call the method:

```
import '../../global_variables.dart';
import '../../main_components/default_button.dart';
class WelcomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        GlobalVariables().init(context);
        final globalVariables = GlobalVariables();
        final screen = GlobalVariables.screen;

        return DefaultButton(
          screen: screen,
          txt: 'Entrar',
          style: kWhiteButtonTextStyle,
          color: kBlackColor,
          function: globalVariables.NavigationToLoginPage(context),
        ),
      }
    }
```

This is the global variables file code:

```
import 'pages/login/login_page.dart';

class GlobalVariables {
  static MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static Size screen;

  NavigationToLoginPage(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
  }
```

And this is the default button class, i have to call this method in the onPressed property.

```
  const DefaultButton({
    Key key,
    @required this.screen,
    @required this.txt,
    @required this.style,
    @required this.color,
    @required this.function,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Size screen;
  final String txt;
  final TextStyle style;
  final Color color;
  final Function function;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      child: Text(
        txt,
        style: style,
      ),
      color: color,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: screen.height * 0.02,
        left: screen.width * 0.3,
        bottom: screen.height * 0.02,
        right: screen.width * 0.3,
      ),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      onPressed: function,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
 return DefaultButton(
      screen: screen,
      txt: 'Entrar',
      style: kWhiteButtonTextStyle,
      color: kBlackColor,
      function: () => globalVariables.NavigationToLoginPage(context),
),
```

Comment: Sorry man, but it didnt work... My screen is black now haha

Comment: I think so, but no precisely, because my app screen is black now, i tried to restart, but didnt work.

Comment: Okay, now onPressed function is working, but there is sthg to do with global variables and it is not pointing toward login page.